# string in xpath

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a string and I want to use  it as a selector in xpath to select a node with name as value of the string.

```
declare variable $get_count := <count><comedy>1</comedy></count>;
(: $string = "comedy" :)
 let $value =  $get_count/$string (: but this doesn't return anything)
```

How shall i do it?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer an easy and immediate solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let $value =  $get_count/$string (: but this doesn't return anything)
```

**Use**:

```
declare variable $get_count := <count><comedy>1</comedy></count>;
declare variable $string := "comedy";

 let $value :=  $get_count/*[name()=$string]
  return 
    $value
```

**When this is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<comedy>1</comedy>
```

Comment: So $get_count holds the `<count>` element node, not a root document node?

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, I have tested this with Saxon under oXygen12.

Comment: @deepti: I am glad my answer was useful. Here at SO, the established way to express gratitude is by accepting an answer (just click on the check-mark beside the answer). :)